# SubSonic data layer that returns POCOs instead of SubSonic's ActiveRecord objects

Tags: .net, orm, subsonic, n-tier-architecture, decoupling

I want to use SubSonic (2.2) in an application I'm building because I like its simplicity and it handles any type of query I can foresee needing. At the same time, I want to keep the upper layers of my application de-coupled from the Subsonic Types. I want to return just Plain Old C# Objects and also pass in POCOs to be saved.

But here's the catch: I want my POCOs to have Lazy loaded properties for Child collections and parent objects based upon the FK relationships. I figure I need to somehow put a Subsonic SqlQuery object in a private member on my POCO and use that internally in the getter for a lazy loaded property.

Any ideas about how to implement this specifically with SubSonic? Anyone done this before?

I do realize that the next major release of SubSonic will do this out-of-box, but that looks to be atleast a few months away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't ever figure out a good way to do this. Subsonic 3 is looking very nice and would solve the problem, but in the mean time we just [went with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508035/t4-template-for-nhibernate-not-fuent-nhibernate).

Answer (score 2):

I use the RepositoryRecord in SubSonic which is "mostly" poco. Then I make partials for those classes that load the other class when a property is selected.

```
Partial Public Class Book

Private _Author as Database.Author 
Property Author() as Database.Author
  Get
     If _Author is nothing then
       ' Load the author class here.
     End if
     return _Author
  End get
  Set
     ....
  End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute:

> tableBaseClass="RepositoryRecord"

I'm afraid I don't know how this handles the lazy loading though. You can see [Rob Conery's post](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/01/16/subsonic-21-pakala-preview-part-2/) about it for more details.

Comment: I have actually tried that option, but RepositoryRecord is a SubSonic thing and therefore I would still be coupled to Subsonic.

I also tried specifying my own base class as the 'tableBaseClass', but that didn't work as I got lots of build errors from the generated files.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not in version 2.x. You might be able to get most of the way there by editing the templates (I have examples of lazy-loaded properties [on my blog](http://john-sheehan.com/blog)). Another option is to build up your pocos then build classes to map from the SubSonic generated classes and queries to your model.