# Tools for NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Can anyone throw some light on tools that can be used with NHibernate and which perform the below mentioned tasks:

1. Generates the Mapping File
2. Generates the Entity Class
3. Generates the Configuration file

And also provide information whether these tools are open source or licensed.
Thanks

Comment: Why would NHibernate need those files if they could be generated automatically?

Comment: @Jørn: It may not be possible to generate the files 100% accurately using a code generator, but it is possible to approach 100% depending on the complexity of the database.  That doesn't mean you should use code generated files without modification, but it can certainly remove quite a bit of grunt work and get you started faster (most other ORMs include code generators like this out of the box).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508035/t4-template-for-nhibernate-not-fuent-nhibernate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703254/nhibernate-code-generation

Comment: @Michael: It's just that, from my experience with NHibernate, I have never felt that I was writing *anything* in my code/mappings that could have been inferred from anything else in my code base.

Comment: @Jørn: Probably because you are doing domain/code first design where as the person asking the question sounds like they already have a database and they want to generate code.  So they are going in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Michael: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for enlightening me :)

Comment: try http://sourceforge.net/projects/ngennhibernatec/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One tool I've used that did a decent job was [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/features/frameworks.aspx). It looked at the existing database and created the entities, mappings and configuration file. However, this is only to be used as a starting point as there are many tweaks you'll likely want to do to make it more usable and better performing. Things such as when to lazy load vs. eager load, creating subclasses or components. This tool really just mimics the database structure in your entities which is not always the best way to represent in code.

This is a licensed solution but it includes a fully functional demo you can use to gen your files initially. After that, you'll most likely just enhance just as you would your database.

Another is [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=1505). Same thing, it'll get you 75% of the way there in most cases.

Just be cautious as to which version of NHibernate these tools are producing. They may be using an older version which may have some obsolete code.

Answer (score 1):

I really like Visual NHibernate (http://www.slyce.com/VisualNHibernate/).
Not free, but has a nice set of features, including the definition of templates for the entities, and generating both HBM.XML as well as Fluent NHibernate mappings.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question with some answers you might find useful is already on SO.
[NHibernate Generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752/nhibernate-generators)

As mentioned in that question's answers, fluent NHibernate is a good option. It just went RTM. You can find more info at http://fluentnhibernate.org/

Answer (score 0):

Check out LLBLGen Pro.  It's got a competing ORM but can also act as a code generator for nhibernate.  Very good for DB first work.